# Egit cannot find private GitHub repo

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

I just signed up for a GitHub micro plan and created my first **private repo**:

```
https://github.com/myproj/repo.git
```

(That's not the real URL). I then installed Egit for Eclipse (Juno), restarted, and tried to import `repo.git`. When I do so I am getting a `Transport Error` from Eclipse. Here are the exact steps I took to arrive at this issue:

Downloading eclipse:

[image]

Installing EGit:

[image]

Importing project from GitHub:

[image]

When I try to search for my repo, Eclipse says it's not found:

[image]

Trying again, via `Git Repository Exploring` perspective:

[image]

"Transport Error": ?!?!

[image]

Being so new to Git, EGit and GitHub, I'm wondering if any of the following are happening:

1. Do I need to do something from inside my GitHub account/repo (e.g., turn something on, adjust a setting, etc.) to make it "searchable" from inside EGit? SSH keys perhaps?
2. Do I need to configure Egit somehow?
3. Am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

The bottom line is: I *believe* this is the "normal" way to install Eclipse and EGit, so I'm perplexed as to why this isn't working. I'm wondering if it's some bug with EGit and private repos? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try adding the repository using "Git Repository Exploring" perspective?

Comment: Thanks @NishantShreshth (+1) - please see my question under ogzd's answer - I have the same question for you!

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `Window > Open Perspective > Git Repository Exploring` and `right click > Paste Repository Path`

Comment: Thanks @ogzd (+1) - when I do that, it's asking me for a port # as well as username/password credentials. I *assume* that the user/password would be my GitHub logins? And what do I use for the port? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes they are Github username & password. You can leave the port as empty, selecting protocol as 'https'

Comment: Thanks again (and again, +1) - however I am now getting a **Transport Error**. Please see my edit to the original question for details.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try `Window > Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > New Entry > http.sslverify=false`

Comment: Thanks again - I tried this but nothing changed. Can you verify that I am using EGit "normally"? That is, the way it normally is used to import a GitHub project? I am getting ready to give up on EGit altogether and use raw `git`.

Comment: Yes, you are in the correct way, to be honest, I have never faced with a `TransportError` before, but it seems like very connected with SSH / SSL issues. Try to search more on SO or Google.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is the problem but you may try adding an SSH key. Described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys).